# primefaces p:ajax update not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.4.2 datatable with in-cell editing. I would like after the edit event method is called, the datatable itself to be updated. I did it like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="timeTable" var="log" value="#{reviewTimesheetBean.lazyModel}" paginator="true"
                            paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="15,30,45,60"
                            paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="2" currentPageReportTemplate="{currentPage} de {totalPages}" lazy="true" editable="true" emptyMessage="#{label['empty.message']}">

  <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{reviewTimesheetBean.onEdit}" update="timeTable" />
   <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{reviewTimesheetBean.onCancel}" update="timeTable" />
....
</p:datatable>
```

But the load method is never called after the rowEdit event. I also tried using the selectors, but it did not work either. Can't the datatable be updated this way?

Thanks

Kelly

Comment: This used to fail in PrimeFaces 3.3 and older. Are you absolutely positive that you're running 3.4.2? Perhaps there's regression.

Comment: Yes I am sure I am using this version... I am going to try an older one than

Comment: just tried with primefaces 3.2 same thing happens...

Comment: I didn't mean that the older one would have worked. I just said that this problem will indeed occur in previous PrimeFaces versions until with 3.3 and that it was fixed thereafter. But, after all, this fix applied to ajax actions on input and command component actions only, not on row editor actions. I can indeed reproduce your problem. Using `@form` also doesn't yield the desired result.

Comment: sorry about that... after posting re-reading what you wrote I realized what you meant.

Comment: if someone is having the same problem, I used this solution using remote command http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1558

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried remoteCommand?

```
<p:remoteCommand name="onCellEdit" action="#{bean.init}" update="formId" ignoreAutoUpdate="true" />
```

And then in your datatable:

```
<p:ajax event="cellEdit" oncomplete="onCellEdit()" listener="#{bean.onCellEdit}" />
```

PS. the remoteCommand is just above the datatable... not sure if that has any impact.

Note the onComplete value must match the name of the remote command.